# How to test recoverSigner and splitSignature

Tags: solidity, testing, openzeppelin-contracts

I am currently trying to test a function that uses a **recoverSigner** inside and I'm not sure how to proceed. Here is the function:

```
  function claimToken(bytes32 message, bytes memory _signature, address nativeTokenAddress, uint256 amount) public {
      require( amount > 0, 'Trying to claim 0 tokens.');
      require(nativeTokenAddress != address(0x0));
      require(recoverSigner(message, _signature) == msg.sender);

      <Extra function code in here... >
  }
```

Here is my test:

```
      it("Should claim tokens provided the native token address exists.", async function () {
        let ropstenTokenFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("RopstenToken");
        let ropstenToken = await ropstenTokenFactory.deploy();
        await ropstenToken.deployed();
    
 expect(await bridgeBase.claimToken("0x81547019bef04f65f91163b765453859aa7b1dc4d0047bd0940adf2cc6b9e84b", "0x81547019bef04f65f91163b765453859aa7b1dc4d0047bd0940adf2cc6b9e84b", ropstenToken.address, 50))
        .to.emit(bridgeBase, "Claimed")
        .withArgs(owner.getAddress(), 50, wrToken.address); 
      });
```

Those two long hash values are for **byte32 message** and **bytes memory _signature** arguments for the claimToken function. When I run that test, I get

> Transaction reverted without a reason string

How can I test a function that has a require for the **recoverySigner**? Also how do I test those functions themselves since I have them in the same contract. The **recoverySigner** and **splitSignature** are the same as in [this question](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/111292/how-to-sign-with-owner-address-and-verify-signature-comes-from-owner)

Comment: You don't want to add an error string or use a custom Error ? Just to know what you are looking for exactly.

Comment: @hroussille I guess the error string doesn't really matter. I just need to figure out how to construct the rsv values and sign a message so I can test splitSignature, then use it to test recoverySigner.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate a valid signature doing something like this ([using ethers](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Signer-signMessage)):

```js
const message = "0x81547019bef04f65f91163b765453859aa7b1dc4d0047bd0940adf2cc6b9e84b"
const signature = bridgeBase.signer.signMessage(arrayify(message));

expect(await bridgeBase.claimToken(message, signature, ropstenToken.address, 50))
  .to.emit(bridgeBase, "Claimed")
  .withArgs(owner.getAddress(), 50, wrToken.address);
```

From your [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/111292/how-to-sign-with-owner-address-and-verify-signature-comes-from-owner) you should be using `isValidData` instead of `recoverSigner` otherwise you are using signatures which are not [EIP-191](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-191) compliant. I don't want to make any assumptions, but from the code you have posted I am quite sure you want the EIP-191 behaviour.